# ClearButton.Width hides inherited member Fuse.Elements.Element.Width

Tags: fusetools

Dev environment:

- Windows 10
- Fuse 1.4.0 (build 14778)

This morning I've noticed I'm getting a warning showing up when I build my project:

```
build\Local\Designer\cache\ux13\ClearButton.g.uno(6.19): W0000: ClearButton.Width hides inherited member Fuse.Elements.Element.Width -- use the 'new' modifier if hiding is intentional

C:\myproject\build\Local\Designer\cache\ux13\ClearButton.g.uno(6,20): Warning W0000: ClearButton.Width hides inherited member Fuse.Elements.Element.Width -- use the 'new' modifier if hiding is intentional(2.0 s)
```

As far as I can tell, I keep getting this warning even when I reset my code back to its state before the warning was showing up.

Doing `uno clean` or manually deleting the `build` folder does not seem to fix the problem either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning originates from the fact that you have created a custom `ux:Class` with the name `ClearButton`, and inside of that class you have defined a `ux:Property` with the name `Width`.

Since `Width` is an already existing default property for all visuals that inherit from `Fuse.Elements.Element` (which is many, if not all) in Fuse, you're essentially hitting a reserved name.
Lucky for you, it's just a warning. It is very likely that you're not experiencing any unwanted side effects, unless you're using the `Width` property in very exotic ways.

To solve the issue and get rid of the warning, give that property a different name.